# Directive throwing error in a Lazy loaded Ionic page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a `SwingDirective` and a `CardsPage`. The page is lazy loaded with `CardsModule`. And `SwingDirective` is part of `AppModule` not lazy loaded. This is

```js
export class SwingDirective {
  @Input() positionChange;
}
```

Here is how swing directive initiated in `cards.html`

```html
<div  swing [positionChange]="positionChange" >
```

Here is `app.module`

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,SwingDirective
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But when I run the app I get an error

> Can't bind to 'positionChange' since it isn't a known property of
>   'div'. ("

Looks like `swing` is not being recognised . Whats am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you on local? Try placing a breakpoint on `SwingDirective` to check if it is even triggered?

Comment: Did you import CommonModule and FormsModule in eager mode?

Comment: @SiddAjmera It is not being triggered. I tried console logging.

Comment: @Gaspar They are part of IonicModule which is importd in AppModule if I am correct.

Comment: When I think about it, why is ionic components and directives not part of every lazy loaded module?